# Why isn't possible to use rebase in such a way that conflicts are only resolved considering the last state of both base and rebased branch?

Tags: git, github, merge, gitlab, rebase

I am puzzled about the inefficiency of rebasing. And after many years I am wondering, why can't this be accomplished?

```
 M1 - M2 - M3 - M4       MASTER 
       \ 
        F1 - F2 - F3     FEATURE BRANCH
```

Imagine M3, M4, F1, F2 and F3 consist of refactors over the same class
This is a headache

So I am wondering, given commits have a reference to full snapshot, wouldn't it be possible to perform rebase in the following fashion?

```
M1 - M2 - M3 - M4 - F1 - F2 - F3'
```

Where M4 and F1 are completely unmerged commits, and F3' is the result of resolving the conflicts of F3 (as last state of the feature branch) against M4 (as last state of the Master Branch)?

Comment: This would create non sensical diffs for `M4 - F1` and `F2 - F3'`. If you don't care about your branch's history, you can go for a squash merge on top of `master`, you would have one single conflict resolution.

Comment: thanks! but why non-sensical? they should simply be huge. And squash would not preserve the original snapshots from my feature branch

Comment: they wouldn't reflect the intention of any developer. Hard resetting to a first content then to another one would probably lead to useless wondering of "what did he mean with this change ?" when reviewing changes.